# How to return file Location after uploading to s3

Tags: express, amazon-s3, sharp

I am new to Node.js and express.

I use following function to upload image to s3.

```
function defaultContentType(req, file, cb) {
    setImmediate(function () {
        var ct = file.contentType || file.mimetype || 'application/octet-stream'
        cb(null, ct);
    });
}

    module.exports = async function (fileName, file) {
        aws.config.update({
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSSecretKey,
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWSAccessKeyId,
            contentType: defaultContentType,
    
        });
    
        var s3bucket = new aws.S3({
            params: {
                Bucket: process.env.S3_Bucket_Name,
            }
        });
    
        var params = {
            Key: fileName,
            Body: file
        };
    
        var fileData = await s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
    
    
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        });
    
        return fileData;

}
```

before uploading the image, I resize it using

```
 request(req.file.location, async function (err, response, body) {
        var fileInstance = await sharp(body);


        var resizeFile = await fileInstance.resize({
            height: 150,
            fit: 'inside'
        });

        var data = await s3Upload('mobile_' + req.file.key, resizeFile);

        req.mobile = data.Location;

        next();
    });
```

The problem I have is;
The image does get resized and saved to s3.

But "s3Upload" function does not return the file location.

Seems like it take some time to complete the operation. Before it get completed, undefined value get return.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

---

Modified method

```
module.exports = function (fileName, file, finishCallback) {
    // more code

    s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            finishCallback(data);
        }
    });

}
```

modified the upload method as

```
s3Upload('mobile_' + req.file.key, resizeFile, (data) => {

            req.mobile = data.Location;
            next();
        });
```

This seems to be working as expected.
I am not really sure this is the correct way to do things.
Is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) the `data.Location` should return the url

Comment: I see, you are mixing async await with callbacks

Comment: change the uploadfunction to this `var fileData = await s3bucket.upload(params).promise()`

Comment: now I am getting error; UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: s3Upload(...).promise is not a function

Comment: try to follow this [official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html)

Comment: or you can manually create a promise from the callback, maybe this can help you out [doc](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-promise-out-of-a-callback-function-in-javascript-d8ec35d1f981/)

Comment: I am new to this area. Found it is difficult to apply the method explained there. I found a workaround to fix my problem (append to my original post). However I really like to know how to do this correctly.